# Where should I put my try and catch in my game?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm building a Number Guessing Game for a lab in school, the basic rules of the game are you have 10 guesses to try to guess the number between 1 and 100. My teacher want me to put all the game logic in one class and use the btn_Click methods in the form class to call methods from the game logic class. I feel like it makes sense to put the try catch in the btn_CLick methods because then I can use MessageBox.show to put a message like "You have to enter a number" or "Then number must be between 1 and 100" and but he said he wants the me to be able to take the code and use it without the form class. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ask yourself: what, exactly, is your reason for having try/catch at all?

Comment: Try/catch is not really for "catching" mistakes made by a user. It's more for dealing with unexpected interactions when interfacing with other system elements, like trying to load a file and that failing for some reason. If a try/catch is required, I'd ask the instructor what specifically it's required for.

Comment: Well, message boxes aren't all that useful when there's no form class, e.g., testing your game without having to manually enter information.

Comment: Try/catch statements don't make sense in this scenario. Not unless you are storing and loading data from a database or a file.

Comment: I think your teacher just wants you to make a separate method to put the try/catch stuff in to make it modular.

Comment: There's validation and there's error handling. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: Create methods in your logic class that take a string parameter for user input. Validate the input before you do anything else with it. E.g. inside a btnClick you would do something like `MyLogicClass.UserResponded(txtUserResponse.Text)` inside this method you simply check 3 things. If the input is blank, if it is a number, and if it is between 1-100. Use string.IsNullOrEmpty(), int.TryParse(string, out int), and a simple value => 1 & value <= 100

Comment: @Adrian: Without seeing the wording in the actually assignment, it's hard to say, but I suspect that is actually the wrong way to do it. The logic class should have a method that excepts a number and returns whether it is too high, too low or correct. The parsing the user input should be entirely in the form class because it's really a UI issue. You could have a text box for entering numbers, a number control, a bunch of numbered buttons, but none of those change the logic of the game class.

Comment: @MattBurland yes you're right that would be the correct way to do it; however, it kind of sounds like the teacher just wants to get them used to splitting up code in general without overwhelming them with design patterns. The assignment seems like a beginner assignment. Either way, it was just a quick "school solution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game logic should be unconcerned with the where and how you get the guesses (numbers) so there really shouldn't be any need for try/catch in the game logic. I'd imagine it would expose a method that might look like this:

```
public GuessResult MakeAGuess(int guess)
```

Notice that it takes an integer which it's going to compare with the target number. So nothing here is going to throw. The body might look something like this:

```
public GuessResult MakeAGuess(int guess)
{
    if (guess > target)
        return GuessResult.TooHigh;
    if (guess < target)
        return GuessResult.TooLow;
    return GuessResult.Correct;
}
```

Where `GuessResult` is a public `enum` with `TooHigh`, `TooLow` and `Correct` values.

Your UI will be responsible for converting strings to numbers (if that's needed) and any try/catching would be done there. BUT, it would be better to use `int.TryParse` rather than `int.Parse` wrapped in a try/catch because it is more efficient. Even better would be to use a more appropriate control on your form to get user input. One that actually is [designed for numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I completely forgot about TryParse thank you. I was using just Parse. And yea now that I thinking about it now and it would make sense to put it in the btn method.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use a try-catch. You could use a TryParse and convert your input from a string into an integer. If it doesn't convert just show an error. If it does convert to an integer you can do an if-then to find out if it's within your wanted parameters.

This could be done via methods contained in the "Logic Class". You could have one method return a true/false that checks if the input is able to be an integer and another that can determine if it's in the range you want.

Your UI would then take those true/falses and display/not display your message box for an error message.

Try/Catches are expensive and it's not useful in this case. If/thens and input validation/sanitation would solve the problems you could have for this program.

Comment: `This could be done via methods contained in the "Logic Class".` It could, but I'd say don't. Validating user input to convert a string to a number is something that the UI layer should handle. The game logic class should *only* take a number and return a result (too high, too low, correct) because *it shouldn't matter how you got the number*. And I suspect that's what the teacher is intending to check.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using try/catch at all unless you really **really** need it.  So for validating user input, instead of attempting to type-cast the value, which may throw an exception, inspect the input string to see if it is an integer.  I'd be surprised if there wasn't already a method for doing this in the C# Library.

Comment: He's using C#, according to the tags.

Comment: Whoops.  I've been jumping between posts.  I must've gotten them mixed up.  Fixed.

Comment: *cough* `int.TryParse`

Comment: Yea someone just mentioned TryParse I completely forgot about it and was just using Parse.